# symbol is multiply defined

Tags: c++

I have a .h file

test.h

```
std::list<std::string> RegisterList;
```

I want to access this list in 2 .c files

A.c

```
#include "test.h"

RegisterList.push_back(myString);
```

B.c

```
#include "test.h"

RegisterList.push_back(myString2);
```

When i compile this code, i get an error
ld: fatal: symbol `RegisteredList' is multiply-defined:

What can be the problem ? Is RegsiterList is initialized by default in test.h which is leading to this problem ?

Answer (score 12):

Because you defined the object in the header file and violated one definition rule. Never define objects in header file.

If you want to use a global object, You need to declare it as extern and define it in one and only one source file.

Answer (score 4):

You need something like:

test.h

```
extern std::list<std::string> RegisterList;
```

A.c

```
#include "test.h"

RegisterList.push_back(myString);
```

B.c

```
#include "test.h"

std::list<std::string> RegisterList;

RegisterList.push_back(myString2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code goes through a chain: `preprocessor` -> `compiler` -> `linker`. Your problem originates with the preprocessor, but doesn't show up until the linker.

`#include` is a pre-processor directive.

Instead of compiling your `.cpp` file, the preprocessor synthesises another file from it, pasting in any included files.

The compiler then compiles the synthetic file producing an object file which contains data definitions, among other things.

You direct the preprocessor to `#include` the header file in two different `.cpp` files, which produces two different object files with the same data defined.

`ld: fatal: symbol 'RegisteredList' is multiply-defined`

This error message is the linker (`ld`) complaining that a global symbol is defined multiple times, and it doesn't know which one to use.

Answer (score 2):

Don't instantiate the variable in a header file. Always instantiate it in a code file, and refer to the instantiation in a header file.